# Enviar parametros de query por e-mail Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, smtp

Como puedo enviar parametros de una query al cuepro de un mensaje, y enviarlo por email.

El e-mail ya se envia, pero necesito enviar parametros.

```
    autorizar=AutorizacionDocumentos.objects.get(id=idDoc.id)



    asunto = 'autorizaciòn'
    mensaje = 'El siguiente mensaje es para notificar...'

    msg = EmailMessage(asunto, mensaje, to=['usuario@gmail.com'])

    msg.send()
```

Answer (score 0):

para añadir información al email necesitas crear antes una plantilla html y enlazarla al correo de la siguiente manera:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

asunto = 'autorizaciòn'
html = render_to_string('plantillaEmail.html',{'parametro1':1,'mensaje':'El siguiente mensaje es para notificar...'}
msg = EmailMessage(asunto, html, to=['usuario@gmail.com'])
msg.send()
```

La plantilla la puedes tratar como otra plantilla cualquiera de Django y referenciar a las variables con `{{parametro1}}`.